# Could not connect to server ProFTPd Debian

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

I am using ProFTPd as my FTP program on my server, but am unable to login to it.
I've enabled MySQL for it so that I can use a web-tool to make users/groups for it. The connection itself seems to be fine, however, logging in doesn't seem to work.

FileZilla is what I use to connect to the server, tells me this:

```
Status: Resolving address of xx.xxxxxxx.xx
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (Debian) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Command:    USER lolmewn
Response:   331 Password required for lolmewn
Command:    PASS **********
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Disconnected from server
```

How can I fix this?

I googled quite a lot, but not many people seem to have had this issue. Most of them had port-forwarding problems, or behind a NAT, which I don't think I have since I do get the welcome message.

Comment: Wrong password.

Comment: @mailq Wow, really? Huh. I thought I set everything up properly... going back to the config room then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check logs if they say anything. You can find them somewhere in `/var/log`

If you can't, my hint would be to start daemon in foreground with high verbosity and see what's happening. How to do that:

As root:
`/usr/sbin/proftpd -n`

End it with:
`Ctrl+C`

Answer (score -3):

Check this directory permissions. They can cause this.